# Oracle Flashback Query with Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I've to use Oracle Flashback Queries in my Java application. We're using Hibernate for data persistence so I'd like to know if there is a way of enable this feature in Hibernate.
Of course I can use SQL queries of Hibernate, but that's not the idea.

Comment: How are you planning to use it ?
Are you looking to simply call a DBMS_FLASHBACK.ENABLE_AT_TIME ?

Comment: Well, I don't know the DB configuration, I just only know that this feature is enabled and I have to make java app use it.
By the moment I've used normal SQL queries. It's a lot of work but if worked.

Answer (score 0):

So far **Hibernate** is not supporting this functionality in a native way (as far as I know), but with the mentioned [ENABLE_AT_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_flashb.htm#sthref3368)  Oracle calll you will be actually able to achive what you want. **Be careful though!** this will enable the "time machine" for the entire session (that could lead to interesting behaviour in case of connection pooling). Here is a full example on correct usage:

```
EXECUTE dbms_flashback.enable_at_time('30-AUG-2000');
--your queries go here
SELECT salary FROM emp where name = 'Joe'
EXECUTE dbms_flashback.disable;
```

**Eclipselink** is something that [supports ("history.as-of")](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/toplink/jpa-extensions-reference/queryhints.htm#TLJPA755) the `as of timestamp` solution, but you have to set it as a `hint`. For example:

```
//...
query.setHint("eclipselink.AS_OF", "2012/10/15 11:21:18.2");
//...
```

Or you can do it via annotation:

```
//...
@QueryHint(name=QueryHints.AS_OF, value="2012/10/15 11:21:18.2");
//...
```

**If you have stick to Hibernate** you should take a look at the incorporated Auditing with the `@Audit` annotation. https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/